# Why cannot numpy arrays convert from datetime to np.datetime64 implicitly?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

Say, I have a `datetime`:

```
given_time = datetime(2013, 10, 8, 0, 0, 33, 945109,
                      tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=60, 
                                                             name=None))
```

I would like to transform it into `np.datetime64`:

```
np.datetime64(given_time)
> numpy.datetime64('2013-10-08T00:00:33.945109+0100')
```

It works well. However, if I have an array of `given_time`:

```
given_times = np.array([given_time]*3) # dtype is object
```

Both `given_times.astype('datetime64')` and `given_times = np.array([given_time] * 3, dtype=np.datetime64)` would trigger `TypeError: Cannot cast datetime.datetime object from metadata [us] to [D] according to the rule 'same_kind'`

So, I have to specify the unit:

```
given_times.astype('datetime64[us]')
# or
given_times = np.array([given_time]*3, dtype='datetime64[us]')
```

My question is, why do I have to specify the unit here? It doesn't require unit in `np.datatime64` constructor.

Comment: Because a numpy array is a homogeneous collection of variables. The same is true of `array.array`.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I am asking why cannot numpy infer the unit in this case, like the way it works here: `np.array(['2007-07-13', '2006-01-13', '2010-08-13'], dtype='datetime64')`

Comment: Good question. What happens with `np.array(np.datetime64(d) for d in [given_time] * 3)`?

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn `np.array(list(np.datetime64(d) for d in [given_time] * 3))` works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but I'd try to answer in case anyone else comes across this.

1. As of 1.11, `numpy` doesn't try to automatically convert iterables of date/datetime objects to datetime64 arrays, this is pretty clear from [this excerpt](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1429c606643d1ad305e710c4a31cb6f398d04c53/numpy/core/tests/test_datetime.py#L227) in the test suite:

```py
# at the moment, we don't automatically convert these to datetime64

dt = datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)
arr = np.array([dt])
assert_equal(arr.dtype, np.dtype('O'))

dt = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 12, 30, 40)     
arr = np.array([dt])
assert_equal(arr.dtype, np.dtype('O'))
```

Ideally, `numpy` would figure that `datetime64` with correct units could be used; see [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3215) issue.

2. When constructing `datetime64` from a scalar, the unit it set to `M8[D]` for date objects and to `M8[us]` for datetime objects ([a relevant test](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1429c606643d1ad305e710c4a31cb6f398d04c53/numpy/core/tests/test_datetime.py#L392)).
3. When you specify `dtype='datetime64'`, or, similarly, `dtype='M8'`, the units are set to "generic", which later resolves to `M8[D]` (although it would be logical to have it resolve to `M8[D]`, see [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3215) issue):

```py
>>> np.datetime_data(np.dtype('datetime64'))
('generic', 1)
>>> np.datetime_data(np.dtype('M8'))
('generic', 1)
>>> np.datetime_data(np.dtype('M8[D]'))
('D', 1)
>>> np.datetime_data(np.dtype('M8[us]'))
('us', 1)
```

4. `given_times.astype('datetime64')` no longer raises an exception -- this was [fixed](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/6465) in 1.11.
5. Starting from 1.11, datetime64 objects [are timezone-naive](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.11.0-notes.rst#highlights), so passing a datetime object with `tzinfo` set like in the provided example will trigger a deprecation warning.