# Python pandas generating first day of month from array of datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, replace, datetimeindex

I am trying to obtain the first day of month from array of datetime i.e. change all days to `1` and all hours to `0`:

```
import pandas as pd
z1 = [datetime(2025, 10, 1, 3, 0),datetime(2025, 1, 6, 7, 0)]
pd.DatetimeIndex(z1).normalize()
DatetimeIndex(['2025-10-01', '2025-01-06'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

I was hoping to achieve

```
DatetimeIndex(['2025-10-01', '2025-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create `Series` from `z1`, then `replace` `day` and convert to [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
print (pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.Series(z1).apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=1)).dt.date))
DatetimeIndex(['2025-10-01', '2025-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Another solution is convert `day` and `hour`:

```
print (pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.Series(z1).map(lambda x: x.replace(day=1, hour=0))))
DatetimeIndex(['2025-10-01', '2025-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be to form a NumPy array of dtype `datetime64[M]` (a datetime64 with monthly resolution)

```
In [31]: np.array(z1, dtype='datetime64[M]')
Out[31]: array(['2025-10', '2025-01'], dtype='datetime64[M]')
```

Passing it to `pd.DatetimeIndex` returns

```
In [32]: pd.DatetimeIndex(np.array(z1, dtype='datetime64[M]'))
Out[32]: DatetimeIndex(['2025-10-01', '2025-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: The error using it with z1 is: TypeError: Cannot cast datetime.datetime object from metadata [us] to [M] according to the rule 'same_kind'. I am using Python 2.7

Comment: @Zanam: What version of NumPy are you using? You might be encountering [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21988714/190597).

Answer (score 3):

use `date_range` and set `freq = 'MS'`. The meaning of `'MS'` can be interpreted from below

[image]

One line of code:

`date_series = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2017', end ='12/1/2019', freq='MS')`