# Numpy converting date object to datetime64[s] in newer version

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

Why numpy started converting date object to datetime64[s] type object in the newer versions ? How to make it backward compatible ?

Example:

**Code snippet**:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

dt = datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)

array = np.array([dt], dtype='datetime64[s]')

array
```

**Result**:

```
**Numpy version 1.12.0**

array(['1970-01-01T00:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[s]')

**Numpy version 1.9.3**

TypeError: Cannot cast datetime.date object from metadata [D] to [s] according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

Comment: Does this answer help http://stackoverflow.com/a/37444604/2254228 ?

Comment: yeah, sort of. Thanks @CMorris.

Answer (score 1):

Try a `'D' intermediate:

```
In [27]: np.array([dt],'datetime64[D]')
Out[27]: array(['1970-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
In [28]: np.array([dt],'datetime64[D]').astype('datetime64[s]')
Out[28]: array(['1970-01-01T00:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

Though in my version, the direct creation works:

```
In [29]: np.array([dt],'datetime64[s]')
Out[29]: array(['1970-01-01T00:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[s]')
In [30]: np.__version__
Out[30]: '1.12.0'
In [31]: dt
Out[31]: datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But then how can I find that the actual unit of dt is 'D' and not 's' ?

Comment: Also, It works in newer version for me too. But I want to check whether dt is datetime64[D] compatible or datetime64[s] compatible ?
Like datetime.date(1970, 1, 1) is datetime64[D] type compatible but datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 10, 30) is datetime64[s] type compatible.